# scp ask to provide passphrase for key without one

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

The following commands are run from a **Terraform** automatic script:

```
sudo chmod 400 /home/ec2-user/key
sudo scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o NoHostAuthenticationForLocalhost=yes -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -i key ec2-user@${aws_instance.master.private_ip}:/home/ec2-user/token
```

Each time I get:

> Enter passphrase for key 'key':

But the key has no passphrase at all.
How can I avoid this prompt ?

---

I run this on **Amazon Linux 2 AMI 2.0.20181008 x86_64 HVM gp2**

Comment: are you sure that `key` is the same as `/home/ec2-user/key`? Are you sure that this is giving you the prompt? Why are you using `sudo`? What's with the quotes and commas?

Comment: yes the same, sudo just to force admin prevelage , double qoutes cause of the script u can neglect

Comment: Please update your question to remove the cruft... Does `ssh-keygen -y -f /home/ec2-user/key` ask for a passphrase?

Comment: @Attie modified the quest , no doesn't ask for It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.

Comment: "_It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others._" ... and after the appropriate `chmod`?

Comment: after chmod ask for the password , any idea how to fix that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84379/discussion-between-ali-and-attie).

Answer (score 1):

> I get Enter passphrase for key 'key': , the key has no passphrase at all

This is a sign that the key file is corrupt, or its contents aren't in a format which the `ssh` program accepts. Some versions of the ssh utility will ask for a passphrase any time it can't make sense of the contents of the key file:

```
$ dd if=/dev/urandom of=key bs=1500 count=1
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1500 bytes transferred in 0.000190 secs (7893922 bytes/sec)
$ chmod 600 key
$ ssh -i key foo@localhost
Enter passphrase for key 'key':
```

More recent versions of `ssh` can tell the difference between a passphrase-protected key and a file full of garbage:

```
$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.6.2
$ dd if=/dev/random of=key bs=1500 count=1
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1500 bytes transferred in 0.000149 secs (10082462 bytes/sec)
$ chmod 600 key
$ ssh -i key localhost
Load key "key": invalid format
Password:
```